# How can I develop this?

Tags: statistics, variance, covariance

$$\operatorname{var}(X - Y)^2 $$
How can I develop this? I think I should arrive at a covariancy, but I can't think of any property.

Comment: What is the question? What do you want to do for this expression?

Comment: This is the question:  Var[(1/2n(n-1)) (X -Y)^2]

Comment: That is just an expression, not a question. What is the *whole* question?

Comment: I put (1/2n(n-1))^2 Var(X -Y )^2

Comment: Can you please write down the original whole question instead of sentence fragments?

Comment: The question is: Var[S^2] = ?

Comment: What is $S$? I mean, the **whole** original problem. A screenshot may be much more helpful. People cannot help without complete information.

Comment: S^2 is the sample mean

Comment: It's: S^2 = (1/n-1) sum(X -Y)^2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean var($ (X-Y)^2 $), that is var ($X^2 - 2XY + Y^2$).  Repeated use of V(A+B) = V(A) + 2 Cov(A,B) + V(B) as well as V(aX) = $a^2$V(X) gives me V($X^2$) -4 Cov($X^2, XY$) + 2Cov($X^2, Y^2$) + 4V(XY) - 4Cov($XY,Y^2$) + V($Y^2$). There is no simple relationship between V(X) and V($X^2$) etc. For example if X were normal, $X^2$ would be a $\chi ^2$ random variable.